# launch activity from preference activity

Tags: android, android-activity

What is the correct way to start an activity from a `PreferenceScreen`?

Here is my code which is not working.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Preference android:title="Change password">
        <intent
            android:targetClass="org.kekem.activity.MyActivity"
            android:targetPackage="org.kekem.activity"/>
    </Preference>
    </PreferenceScreen>`

The activity is also declared within my manifest file as follows:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MyActivity"
        android:label="Change password"
        android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

This error is thrown:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity
class org.kekem.activity/org.kekem.activity.MyActivity have you declared
this   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `targetPackage` attribute on your `<intent>` tag should be the package ID (also known as the application ID) of your application, not the name of the Java package in which your Activity resides.

Thus your `<intent>` should probably be something like this, assuming your application ID is `org.kekem`:

```
<intent
    android:targetClass="org.kekem.activity.MyActivity"
    android:targetPackage="org.kekem"/>
```

Comment: Great answer @Tanis.7x. I had changed the src package of my application after it was released but the applicationID remained the same. After reading your post I actually checked the gradle file and the applicationID is different from the src package. Now it is working as a charm. I can now move forward. Big thanks.